# Better architecture for Delta tables performance speed in querying?

Tags: pyspark, database-design, databricks, delta-lake

We deal with billions of records. Millions everyday.
For the data lake storage needs we are using Delta.  Data written in S3 and using unity catalog SQL querying.

We did all optimizations to improve delta querying speed mentioned in
https://docs.delta.io/latest/optimizations-oss.html.
https://docs.delta.io/latest/best-practices.html

1. Partitions
2. Optimize in regular interval
3. Auto Compaction
4. Z-order indexing & Few more.

But still our Delta querying is very slow.  It is taking 8 to 20 seconds to return data based on size of data. Some tables has 70 columns and some has 400 columns (Please don't ask why 400 columns :D )

**Problem statement:**
I want to read data within a second.  What is the solution we can go with ?  I am thinking of having a distributed cache layer on top of Delta.  Did not check this yet.  Want suggestions.

Comment: Are you open to real-time distributed systems like Kafka? if so, I would suggest setting up Kafka since you want to be able to read data within a second

Comment: Sorry.  I am not able to visualize the solution. Kafka is for messaging or real time streaming right?  How any application will read data from Delta tables by using Kafka ?  Can you please give little more steps ?